# Python - Segregate List by Initials

Tags: python, sorting, pygame

I want to be able to separate my contacts list by the first letter of the a contacts name i.e

```
A
----------
#All contacts under A

B
----------
#All contacts under B

etc...
```

All my contacts are instances of a `Contact` class, which is stored in a list. The code used to sort them alphabetically is

```
addressBook.contactsList.sort(key = lambda c: (c.lastName, c.firstName) if c.lastName else (c.firstName, ""))
```

I am currently working with PyGame in order to develop the GUI and so far I have managed to print the list contacts without a problem except the one I'm asking now. It currently looks 'messy' since contacts are listed together in one go without any divider to show clarity.

I want the divider generated to be given a style of my choosing to firstly go with the rest of the GUI look and also to show to end users that it is a divider.

The three classes used to generate the GUI screen are defined as follows:

```
class Contact():
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, address, groupType,
                 telephone, mobile, email, photoField):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = address
        self.groupType = groupType
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.email = email
        self.photoField = photoField

    def showDetails(self):
        print("First Name:\t", self.firstName)
        print("Last Name:\t", self.lastName)
        print("Address:\t", self.address)
        print("Telephone:\t", self.telephone)
        print("Mobile:\t", self.mobile)
        print("Email:\t", self.email)

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        firstName = input("First Name: ")
        lastName = input("Last Name: ")
        address = input("Address: ")
        telephone = input("Telephone: ")
        mobile = input("Mobile: ")
        email = input("Email: ")
        return cls(firstName, lastName, address, None,

                   telephone, mobile, email, None)

class AddressBook():
    def __init__(self):
        self.contactsList = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))

    def addContact(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            contact = Contact.from_input()
        self.contactsList.append(contact)
        pickle.dump(self.contactsList, open("save.p", "wb"))

    def delContact(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            search = input("Search: ")
            for i in self.contactsList:
                 if (i.firstName.lower() == search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() == search.lower()):
                    indexed = self.contactsList.index(i)
                    del self.contactsList[indexed]
                    pickle.dump(self.contactsList, open("save.p", "wb"))
                elif (i.firstName.lower() != search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() != search.lower()):
                    continue

    def contactInfo(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            search = input("Search: ")
            print()

            #display contact information
            for i in self.contactsList:
                if (i.firstName.lower() == search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() == search.lower()):
                    i.showDetails()
                    print()
                elif (i.firstName.lower() != search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() != search.lower()):
                    continue
                else:
                    print("No contacts\n")

    def contactSearch(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            search = input("Search: ")
            print()

            for i in self.contactsList:
                if (i.firstName.lower() == search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() == search.lower()):
                    print(i.firstName, i.lastName)
                    print()
                elif (i.firstName.lower() != search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() != search.lower()):
                    continue
                else:
                    print("No contacts\n")

class MainPage(Page):
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480)), caption = pygame.display.set_caption("Contacts"), title = "Contacts"):
        Page.__init__(self, screen, caption)
        self.title = title

    def style(self):
        Page.style(self)
        titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 38)
        textSurface = titleFont.render(self.title, True, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.blit(textSurface, (5, 18))
        AddButton().shape()

    #Presenting contacts on page
    def printContacts(self):
        addressBook = AddressBook()
        addressBook.contactsList
        addressBook.contactsList.sort(key = lambda c: (c.lastName, c.firstName) if c.lastName else (c.firstName, ""))
        contactFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 18)
        x = 80

        for i in addressBook.contactsList:
            name = i.firstName + " " + i.lastName
            textName = contactFont.render(name, True, (0,0,0))
            pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (210,210,210), (5,(x+20)), (320, (x+20)), 1)
            self.screen.blit(textName, (5, x))
            x += 30
```

I really have no clue about how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your data:

```
from itertools import groupby

...
    # group contactsList by first letter of lastName
    for (key, g) in groupby(addressBook.contactsList, lambda c: c.lastName[0]):
        # draw divider here
        groupName = contactFont.render(key, True, (0,0,0))
        self.screen.blit(groupName, (5, x))
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, ...)

        for i in g:
            name = i.firstName + " " + i.lastName
            textName = contactFont.render(name, True, (0,0,0))
            pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (210,210,210), (5,(x+20)), (320, (x+20)), 1)
            self.screen.blit(textName, (5, x))
            x += 30
```

Also, it seems your variable `x` should be named `y`, since it represents the `y` coordinate.

Comment: I swapped the x with the y, however using your method the Shell keeps returning `IndexError: string index out of range` from `for (key, g) in groupby(addressBook.contactsList, lambda c: c.lastName[0]):` Any ideas why it's doing this?

Comment: @RoyalSwish Yes. There's a `lastName` which is an empty string. You could do something like `lambda c: c.lastName[0] if c.lastName else '-'` to handle those cases